# Replace control char in xmlelement

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

**Context**

Some PL/SQL package created to generate XML are throwing this error :

```
ORA-31061: Erreur XDB : special char to escaped char conversion failed.
```

This error happen because some of the text selected in the xmlelement contains control characters which are not allowed.

**Solution**

Replace all control chars of each xmlelement with a regex :

```
xmlelement("foo", REGEXP_REPLACE (bar, '[[:cntrl:]]', ''))
```

**Problem with solution**

I have 8 packages of about 5k rows each where almost each row is an xmlelement.

**Other potential solution**

I tought I could write a regex to replace each xmlelement's value automatically, but it fails when I have xmlelement in xmlelement with subquery and sub-subquery etc.

**My Question**

Is there a smarter way then replacing each xmlelement's value one by one ? I was asked to do all xmlelement of each packages to prevent further bugs but I'm sure there is a better way of doing this.

**Edit**

For example, you can reproduce the bug with this query :

```
select xmlelement("foo", unistr('\0013b')) from dual;
```

And I would fix it using this query :

```
select xmlelement("foo", regexp_replace(unistr('\0013b'), '[[:cntrl:]]', '')) from dual;
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you but take a look at this page https://community.oracle.com/thread/595376?tstart=0. I hope it can give you some insight

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is exactly what you want, but it is possible to generate xml for your query without error using dbms_xmlgen.  Here is an example:

```
declare
    xml_output CLOB;
    my_context dbms_xmlgen.ctxHandle;
begin
    my_context := dbms_xmlgen.newcontext('select unistr (''\0013b'') from dual');
    xml_output := dbms_xmlgen.getxml(my_context);
    dbms_xmlgen.closecontext(my_context);
    dbms_output.put_line(xml_output);
end;
```

Comment: You're right, this is not exactly what I want since my goal is to avoid rewriting the 40k lines or automatically write.

Still, thanks for your answer as I did not know dbms_xmlgen wouldn't throw error for control chars.